# React lifecycle render called before componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am slightly confused with the way lifecycle order/execution happens and how things render in the DOM.

So if I take the below example, what I find is after 5 seconds, the control goes to `render` before it goes to `componentDidUpdate`. However, in render, it is able to print the updated state value i.e. XYZ even before `componentDidUpdate` is invoked. So how does this work and while componentDidUpdate says we can access DOM nodes inside it, I somehow was thinking that `componentDidUpdate` is when the state actually gets updated. Not sure where the difference is in terms of my understanding?

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    
    export default class getSnapshotBeforeUpdateMethod extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        console.log("1 constructor");
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: "ABC"
        };
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log("2a componentDidMount");
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("2b Inside componentDidMount");
          this.setState({ name: "XYZ" });
        }, 3000);
      }
      getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log("3 getSnapshotBeforeUpdate");
        document.getElementById("previous-state").innerHTML =
          "The previous state was " + prevState.name;
      }
      componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("4 componentDidUpdate");
        document.getElementById("current-state").innerHTML =
          "The current state is " + this.state.name;
      }
      render() {
        console.log("5 render");
        return (
          <>
            <h5>This is a {this.state.name}</h5>
            <p id="current-state"></p>
            <p id="previous-state"></p>
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/class-lifecycle-method-order-0zjk4?file=/src/App.js:0-1055

Comment: *the control goes to render before it goes to componentDidUpdate*. What else are you expecting. This is what lifecycle methds are `render` -> `componentDidUpdate`. [please see the image](https://i2.wp.com/programmingwithmosh.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-31-at-1.44.28-PM.png?ssl=1)

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` will get called after the dom gets update.

Comment: you can read about batching in react in this [Link](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a review of the [react lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) may help.

[image]

Take note that the `render` lifecycle method is invoked during the "render phase" when React is rendering out the virtualDOM in order to compute the diff it needs to commit, or flush, to the actual DOM. Note also that the functions/methods during this phase are ***pure and have no side effects***, and may be ***paused, aborted, or restarted by React*** (*emphasis mine*).

Now note that `componentDidUpdate` occurs during the "commit phase" when the DOM has been updated and rendered.

Your `console.log` in the `render` method is an unintentional side-effect, but it's showing you when it was called relative to `componentDidUpdate`.

`render` is called once, or possibly multiple times, *before* `componentDidUpdate` is called once, per render cycle.

Comment: Thanks...So in the diagram, I see render box as well as one more box which says "Reac updates DOM and refs"...So what is the difference between the two...I would think that render box would itself imply that DOM would be rendered/printed to screen ?

Comment: @copenndthagen The render box is the `render` lifecycle method. The entire component tree ***must*** be rendered in order to see what changed. The "React updates DOM and refs" box is the change being applied to the DOM, i.e. what you often consider to be the "render", in other words, what you see rendered and updated on the screen. React calling the `render` lifecycle method ***is not*** the same thing as the component being rendered out to the DOM.

Comment: Ok got it....but say if during the render phase, there is some div which contains this.state.someStateVar and if someStateVar was "ABC" when React callled "render", I assume there is no further possibility after this for this state value to get updated now i.e. when it says React updates DOM and refs, it would print "ABC" to the screen now and no other value.

Comment: Just to add, as per the diagram link below, I see getSnapShotBeforeUpdate between the 2 things, https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DZ-97vzW4AAbcZj?format=jpg&name=large

However, I assume this is just a read thing and we cannot update any state here...

Comment: @copenndthagen Affirmative, at *that* point React has completed the "render phase" and is now switching to commit to the DOM, getting the snapshot of the DOM *just* before it's updated so any values read/captured there are passed to `componentDidUpdate` as the third argument.